# Oxygen sensor malfunction

Tags: engine, toyota, o2-sensor

2005 Toyota Tundra v8

This truck overheats with no radiator fluid loss. Also had power loss. Motor shake. Codes came back with a voltage high/low and both oxygen sensors upstream needed replacement.

Replaced O2 sensors precat and now she runs stronger but overheats still. Shake stopped.

Now downstream O2 codes triggered.

1) can faulty O2 sensors cause overheating by running too lean or rich?

Comment: What evidence do you have that it is overheating?

Comment: Temp gauge.... Both rad hoses hard n hot....

Comment: Side note... Switched out spark plugs... Bank 1 white bank 2 brown.... This was pre O2 sensor switch out...

Comment: Dee, could you get us the exact codes? P0xxx, preferably with a description.

Comment: Will do after work @zaid

Comment: When you say pre cat o2 sensors I assume you mean AFR sensors? And faulty o2s/AFRs will never contribute to an overheat condition. You need to nail down whatever is causing your overheating first. How's the fan clutch? When does it over heat? How's the overflow reservoir fluid level?

Comment: All the above are good... Reservoir and rad are to spec... Fan is belt driven so it's always working.... Overheats when accelerated/driven but not at idle.... It tends to get hotter after 65

Comment: But if O2 cause a lean situation; it could raise cylinder temp and possibly melt positions no?

Comment: @Dee it could if you're driving a very lean working engine hard, in other situations a well functioning cooling system should take care of that. Check if your thermostat isn't stuck closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad O2 sensors **can** contribute extra heat to the system, but **usually** they have the opposite effect.  When the ECU detects that the sensors are faulty, the engine will default to open-loop mode, which should cause a properly functioning engine to run a rich A/F ratio.  This actually has the effect of cooling the combustion charge and removing more heat from the exhaust.

The fact that bank 1's plugs are white confirms your overheat condition and/or indicates a lean A/F ratio.  The fact that you are getting voltage high/low error codes leads me to believe that you may not be able to trust your electronics until the source of that error is corrected, as the ECU may be having problems reading the correct/expected input from the sensors.  I would suspect the alternator's voltage regulator.  If overvoltage is occurring, it may actually be *causing* your O2 sensors to fail.

EDIT: When an engine is hot, the radiator hoses will always be "hard and hot."  The system gets pressurized (by design) as water under added pressure boils at a hotter temperature than water at atmospheric pressure.

EDIT #2: Even an engine that **is** running lean will not usually cause the engine to overheat (on the coolant temp. gauge) **if** the cooling system is functioning correctly.

Comment: That does answer my question and sheds light on direction needed. Thx!

Comment: Sure thing - happy to help!